# In NetSuite can you do a saved search of all Custom Entities created

Tags: field, netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to put together a list of all the Custom Entity Fields that we have created.
But I also need the Description values and the Help Values.

Use Case: We have many fields that do not have a description, or Help Value and I am wanting to go through and update those.  And want to be able to skip the ones that have a description already.